# Dynamic Array in C - realloc

Tags: c

I know how to build Dynamically allocated arrays, but not how to grow them.

for example I have the following interface..

```
void insertVertex( vertex p1, vertex out[], int *size);
```

This method takes a vertex and stores it into the  out array. After storing the vertex I increase the count of length for future calls.

p1 - is the vertex I'm going to add.

out[] - is the array I need to store it in (which is always full)

length - the current length

Vertex is defined as..

```
typedef struct Vertex{
int x;
int y;
} Vertex;
```

This is what I'm using in Java..

```
Vertex tempOut = new Vertex[size +1];
//Code to deep copy each object over
tempOut[size] = p1;
out = tempOut;
```

This is what I believed I could use in c..

```
out = realloc(out, (*size + 1) * sizeof(Vertex));
out[(*size)] = p1;
```

However, I keep on receiving an error message that the object was not allocated dynamically.

I found a solution that will resolve this.. Instead of using Vertex* I was going to switch to Vertex** and store pointers vs. vertex. However, after switching everything over I found out that I over looked the fact that the unit test will be providing me a Vertex out[] that everything has to be stored in.

I have also tried the following with no luck.

```
Vertex* temp = (Vertex *)malloc((*size + 1) * sizeof(Vertex));
for(int i = 0; i < (*size); i++)
{
temp[i] = out[i];
}
out = temp;
```

However, no matter what I do when I test after both of these the array returned has not changed.

**Update - Requested information**

out - is defined as an array of Vertex (Vertex out[])

It is originally built with the number of vertex in my polygon. For example.

out = (Vertex *)malloc(vertexInPolygon * sizeof(Vertex))

Where vertexInPolygon is an integer of the number of vertex in the polygon.

length was a typo that should have been size.

Size is an integer pointer

```
int *size = 0;
```

Each time a vertex is in the clipping plane we add it to the array of vertex and increase the size by one.

**Update**

To better explain myself I came up with a short program to show what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vertex {
    int x, y;
} Vertex;

void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex out[], int *size);

void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex out[], int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;
    
    out = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
    out[(*size)] = v1;
    
    //  Update Size
    *size = newSize;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //  This would normally be provided by the polygon
    int *size = malloc(sizeof(int)); *size = 3;
    
    //  Build and add initial vertex
    Vertex *out = (Vertex *)malloc((*size) * sizeof(Vertex));
    Vertex v1; v1.x = 1; v1.y =1;
    Vertex v2; v2.x = 2; v2.y =2;
    Vertex v3; v3.x = 3; v3.y =3;
    
    out[0] = v1;
    out[1] = v2;
    out[2] = v3;
    
    //  Add vertex
    //  This should add the vertex to the last position of out
    //  Should also increase the size by 1;
    Vertex vertexToAdd; vertexToAdd.x = 9; vertexToAdd.y = 9;
    addPointerToArray(vertexToAdd, out, size);
    
    for(int i =0; i < (*size); i++)
    {
        printf("Vertx: (%i, %i) Location: %i\n", out[i].x, out[i].y, i);
    }
   
}
```

Comment: What is `out` defined as? What are `length` and `size`?

Comment: You said `realloc` complained that it wasn’t allocated dynamically. So... was it? You have to use `malloc` first in order to be able to use `realloc` later.

Comment: Can you also show the definition of `length` or `size` before it's passed to `insertVertex()`

Comment: evgeny out is defined as...

Vertex *out = (Vertex *)malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * numOfVerInPolygon)

Where numOfVerInPolygon is the number of vertex in the polygon.

Daniel Brockman
Yes, it is defined with malloc. Before it is passed it is defined as the following.
Vertex *out = (Vertex *)malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * numOfVerInPolygon)

TimothyJones
Sorry, length and size are the same thing. I updated the post so that everything uses size.

size starts out as zero:

int *size = 0;

As we go through each vertex if its in the clipping plain the size is increase by one after added to the out[](Vertex)

Comment: `int *size = 0` would initialize size with NULL, and point it at nothing -- not give you a pointer to an `int` set to 0.  Unless you're pointing it at an actual `int` later, this may be your problem.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Should this be under another tag? I figured that my main question was based on realloc * malloc that c was the correct tag. If its not C what is it?

Comment: This compiles fine on GCC, however your compiler may be seeing the [] as an array pointer. Try replacing void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex out[], int *size) with void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex *out, int *size)

Comment: @Aslai Thank you! When I moved the code over to one of our linux machines it compiled & ran without any issues.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Chris you must have missed the line above that example that reads "This is what i'm using in java..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One long-term problem is that you are not returning the updated array pointer from the `addPointerToArray()` function:

```
void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex out[], int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;

    out = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
    out[(*size)] = v1;

    //  Update Size
    *size = newSize;
}
```

When you reallocate space, it can move to a new location, so the return value from `realloc()` need not be the same as the input pointer.  This might work while there is no other memory allocation going on while you add to the array because `realloc()` will extend an existing allocation while there is room to do so, but it will fail horribly once you start allocating other data while reading the vertices.  There are a couple of ways to fix this:

```
Vertex *addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex out[], int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;

    out = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
    out[(*size)] = v1;

    //  Update Size
    *size = newSize;
    return out;
}
```

and invocation:

```
out = addPointerToArray(vertexToAdd, out, size);
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a pointer to the array:

```
void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex **out, int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;

    *out = realloc(*out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
    (*out)[(*size)] = v1;

    //  Update Size
    *size = newSize;
}
```

and invocation:

```
out = addPointerToArray(vertexToAdd, &out, size);
```

Neither of these rewrites addresses the subtle memory leak.  The trouble is, if you overwrite the value you pass into `realloc()` with the return value but `realloc()` fails, you lose the pointer to the (still) allocated array - leaking memory.  When you use `realloc()`, use an idiom like:

```
Vertex *new_space = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
if (new_space != 0)
    out = new_space;
else
    ...deal with error...but out has not been destroyed!...
```

Note that using `realloc()` to add one new item at a time leads to (can lead to) quadratic behaviour.  You would be better off allocating a big chunk of memory - for example, doubling the space allocated:

```
int newSize = *size * 2;
```

If you are worried about over-allocation, at the end of the reading loop, you can use `realloc()` to shrink the allocated space to the exact size of the array.  However, there is then a bit more book-keeping to do; you need to values: the number of vertices allocated to the array, and the number of vertices actually in use.

Finally, for now at least, note that you should really be ruthlessly consistent and use `addPointerToArray()` to add the first three entries to the array.  I'd probably use something similar to this (untested) code:

```
struct VertexList
{
    size_t    num_alloc;
    size_t    num_inuse;
    Vertex   *list;
};

void initVertexList(VertexList *array)
{
    // C99: *array = (VertexList){ 0, 0, 0 };
    // Verbose C99: *array = (VertexList){ .num_inuse = 0, .num_alloc = 0, .list = 0 };
    array->num_inuse = 0;
    array->num_alloc = 0;
    array->list      = 0;
}

void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, VertexList *array)
{
    if (array->num_inuse >= array->num_alloc)
    {
        assert(array->num_inuse == array->num_alloc);
        size_t new_size = (array->num_alloc + 2) * 2;
        Vertex *new_list = realloc(array->list, new_size * sizeof(Vertex));
        if (new_list == 0)
            ...deal with out of memory condition...
        array->num_alloc = new_size;
        array->list      = new_list;
    }
    array->list[array->num_inuse++] = v1;
}
```

This uses the counter-intuitive property of `realloc()` that it will do a `malloc()` if the pointer passed in is null.  You can instead do a check on `array->list == 0` and use `malloc()` then and `realloc()` otherwise.

You might notice that this structure simplifies the calling code too; you no longer have to deal with the separate `int *size;` in the main program (and its memory allocation); the size is effectively bundled into the `VertexList` structure as `num_inuse`.  The main program might now start:

```
int main(void)
{
    VertexList array;
    initVertexList(&array);
    addPointerToArray((Vertex){ 1, 1 }, &array);  // C99 compound literal
    addPointerToArray((Vertex){ 2, 2 }, &array);
    addPointerToArray((Vertex){ 3, 3 }, &array);
    addPointerToArray((Vertex){ 9, 9 }, &array);

    for (int i = 0; i < array->num_inuse; i++)
        printf("Vertex %d: (%d, %d)\n", i, array->list[i].x, array->list[i].y, i);

    return 0;
}
```

(It is coincidental that this sequence will only invoke the memory allocation once because the new size `(old_size + 2) * 2` allocates 4 elements to the array the first time.  It is easy to exercise the reallocation by adding a new point, or by refining the formula to `(old_size + 1) * 2`, or ...

If you plan to recover from memory allocation failure (rather than just exiting if it happens), then you should modify `addPointerToArray()` to return a status (successful, not successful).

Also, the function name should probably be `addPointToArray()` or `addVertexToArray()` or even `addVertexToList()`.

Comment: Leffier
Thank you. Both you and Santoj really helped me out. I have updated my method and wanted to know if this would be ok.

'void addPointerToPointerArray(Vertex v1, Vertex **out, int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;
    Vertex *tempOut = (Vertex *)malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * newSize);
    
    if (tempOut != 0) 
    {
        
        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < *size) 
        {
            tempOut[i] = (*out)[i];
            i++;
        }
        
        free(*out);
        *out = tempOut;
    }
    
    (*out)[(*size)] = v1;
    *size = newSize;
}'

Comment: Yes - with caveats.  The `while` loop should probably be a `for` loop, or replaced with a `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  Using `realloc()` means you would not do the copy yourself, and it might not need to copy everything.  Incrementing the size by one each time becomes a problem as you use the function more, especially in this 'always copy' mode.  The first time you add one, you copy 3 items; the next, you copy 4; the next, you copy 5, etc.  But what you have looks like it should do the job.  (I reformatted it to eyeball it; I did not run it past a compiler, much less `valgrind`.)

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for your consideration:
1. **Don't use the same input & output parameter while using `realloc`** as it can return `NULL` in case memory allocation fails & the memory pointed previously is leaked. `realloc` may return new block of memory (Thanks to @Jonathan Leffler for pointing out, I had missed this out). You could change your code to something on these lines:

```
Vertex * new_out = realloc(out,  newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
if( NULL != new_out )
{    
    out = new_out;
    out[(*size)] = v1;
}
else
{
 //Error handling & freeing memory
}
```

2. Add `NULL` checks for `malloc` calls & handle errors when memory fails.
3. Calls to `free` are missing.
4. Change the return type of `addPointerToArray()` from `void` to `bool` to indicate if the addition is successful. In case of `realloc` failure you can return failure say, false else you can return success say, true.
Other observations related to excessive copies etc, are already pointed out by @MatthewD.
And few good observations by @Jonathan Leffler (:
Hope this helps!

Comment: +0.5: you've made some good points - notably about the misuse of `out = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));`.  However, you've not mentioned the crucial point that `realloc()` might return a different pointer than the one supplied - the data might move.  That fact demands a different strategy; see my answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks a lot! I had missed it out ... response edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample program works fine for me. I'm using gcc 4.1.1 on Linux.

However, if your actual program is anything like your sample program, it is rather inefficient!

For example, your program copies memory a lot: structure copies - initialising `out`, passing vertices to `addPointerToArray()`, memory copies via `realloc()`.

Pass structures via a pointer rather than by copy.

If you need to increase the size of your list type a lot, you might be better off using a linked list, a tree, or some other structure (depending on what sort of access you require later).

If you simply have to have a vector type, a standard method of implementing dynamically-sized vectors is to allocate a block of memory (say, room for 16 vertices) and double its size everytime you run out of space. This will limit the number of required reallocs.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes , it should work.

```
void addPointerToArray(Vertex v1, Vertex (*out)[], int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size;
    newSize++;

    *out = realloc(out, newSize * sizeof(Vertex));
    *out[(*size)] = v1;

    //  Update Size
    *size = newSize;
}
```

and call the function like

```
addPointerToArray(vertexToAdd, &out, size);
```

- There is a simple way to fix these type of issue (you might already know this). When you pass a argument to a function, think what exactly goes on to the stack and then combine the fact that what ever changes you make to variables present on stack would vanish when come out the function. This thinking should solve most of the issues related to passing arguments.
- Coming to the optimization part, picking the right data structure is critical to the success of any project. Like somebody pointed out above, link list is a better data structure for you than the array.